# ObjectListView Nested Objects

Tags: c#, winforms, objectlistview

I am currently trying to use TreeListView, and I was wondering how you would find values of three layered nested object, where the layers are location, then system, then device.

```
private void initObjectListView()
    {
        // Can the given object be expanded?
        this.treeListView1.CanExpandGetter = delegate(Object x)
        {
            return x is Location;
        };

        // What objects should belong underneath the given model object?
        this.treeListView1.ChildrenGetter = delegate(Object x)
        {
            if (x is Location)
                return ((Location)x).systemMap.Values;


            throw new ArgumentException("Unknown TreeListView Object - Should a Location Type");
        };
    }
```

There is a concurrent dictionary systemMap (string,Device) where the string is the name of the device, and the device is a device object itself.

I got it to a point where if i replace

```
return ((Location)x).systemMap.Values;
```

with

```
return ((Location)x).systemMap["System 1"].deviceMap.Values;
```

I would get the correct ListView for that specific system I wanted, but obviously I want it done to all systems in the system map, instead of system 1.

```
return ((Location)x).systemMap.Values;
```

only shows up to location, then systems under the location, but does not show devices under system.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample run: [image: sample run]

Model classes:

```
// column aspect names are the names of these properties
public class AspectBindable
{
  public string ObjectName { get; set; }
  public string ObjectType { get; set; }
}
// level 2 info
public class Sistem : AspectBindable { public IList <Device> Devices { get; set; } }

//level 1
public class Location : AspectBindable { public IList<Sistem> Systems { get; set; } }

//level 3 
public class Device : AspectBindable { }
```

Form constructor:

```
public Form31683555 ( )
{
  InitializeComponent();
  // control expansion
  this.tlv.CanExpandGetter = delegate(object x)
  {
    if (x is Sistem)
      return !ObjectListView.IsEnumerableEmpty((x as Sistem).Devices);
    else if (x is Location)
      return !ObjectListView.IsEnumerableEmpty((x as Location).Systems);
    else if (x is Device)
      return false;
    else
      throw new ArgumentException("x");
  };
  // node children
  this.tlv.ChildrenGetter = delegate(object x) {
    if (x is Sistem)
      return (x as Sistem).Devices;
    else if (x is Location)
      return (x as Location).Systems;
    else if (x is Device)
      return null;
    else
      throw new ArgumentException("x");
  };
  // TreeListView first order parent level
  this.tlv.Roots = new Location[] { 
    new Location { 
      Systems = new Sistem[] { 
        new Sistem { 
          Devices = new Device[] { 
            new Device { ObjectName = "Device 1.1.1", ObjectType="some device"},
            new Device { ObjectName = "Device 1.1.2", ObjectType="a device"}
          },
          ObjectName = "System 1.1", ObjectType = "system"
        },
        new Sistem { 
          Devices = new Device[] { 
            new Device { ObjectName = "Device 1.2.1", ObjectType="device"},
            new Device { ObjectName = "Device 1.2.2", ObjectType="another device"}
          },
          ObjectName = "System 1.2", ObjectType = "another system"
        },            
      },
      ObjectType = "location 1", ObjectName="full location"
    },
    new Location {ObjectName = "empty", ObjectType="location"}
  };
}
```